# Having trouble with starting tomcat server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, launch

I have a problem when starting TOmcat 6 server from eclipse, it pops up with the following message:

```
Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

Comment: 1. Right click on Tomcat server link in Servers tab of eclipse Select 2. Open -> it opens "Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost" page in Editor 3. At the right side "Timeouts" section, it says "Specify the time limit to complete server operations.", default start (in seconds) is "45" seconds Change to whatever you like in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that it just takes too long to start-up. You can check that from your logs to see whether it was midway through when the default 45 secs cutt-off time occurred. If so, on the `Servers` view double-click on the tomcat instance you are deploying and in the *Overview* tab, click on the `Timeouts` section on the right column and give your tomcat a bit more time to startup.